# pyspark-mongodb collection read command won't execute

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following versions installed :-
spark 2.1.0,
scala 2.11.6,
mongoDB 3.2.17

I tried to start the pyspark shell with following command

```
./bin/pyspark --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
```

after this i started spark session as follows

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp").config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mycollection.dummy").config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mycollection.dummy").getOrCreate()
```

i performed writing to a collection in mongodb db and it is getting executed successfully

but, when i try to read the collection using the command

```
df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/mycollection.dummy").load()
```

it is showing error as follows

`17/10/13 10:43:33 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.TypeCoercion$.findTightestCommonType()Lscala/Function2;
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MongoInferSchema$$compatibleType(MongoInferSchema.scala:135)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$$anonfun$3.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:78)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$$anonfun$3.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an inconsistency in the dataframe reading line. First of all, you initialize `my_spark`, but then use `spark`. You also use `"uri"`, instead of `"spark.mongodb.input.uri"`. Try this below:

```
df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/mycollection.dummy").load()
```

Otherwise provide more code to check as a whole.

Comment: sorry, there's a mistake while posting. I used my_spark only, not spark. I will edit that in the post and it was some py4j error, it seems. I re-installed it and now it seems to be working fine. thanks, anyway.

Comment: Please, post your solution! I have the same problem!

Comment: Haha, I did use `spark` vs `my_spark`, but unfortunately the error persists (in zeppelin). The exact same commands work in pyspark on master...